# How can I pipe from Get-Content -Wait?

Tags: powershell, wait, pipeline

I would like to pipe the output of `Get-Content $file -Wait` to a custom PowerShell script. The script looks like this.

```
$lines = ($input | Out-String) -replace "`r", "" -split "`n"

foreach ($line in $lines) {
    #Process $line

    Write-Host $line
}
```

Basically the idea is to take the input, format it nicely and then process the output before it gets printed to the console.

The problem is nothing is getting sent to my script when I call it like `cat $file -Wait | MyScript`. If I do `cat $file -Wait` or `cat $file | MyScript`, everything works as expected. But combining the pipe and the wait parameter doesn't work.

Is there some syntax I need to use to allow processing the `-Wait` parameter? I tried using `Out-String -Stream`, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: You realize you do `$lines =` and then `ForEach($line in $input)` making the first line completely useless? Also, are you really taking an array of strings, outputting it as a multi-line string, removing CRs, and then splitting it back into an array of strings? Is there a point to that?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Sorry about that. There was a typo where `$input` should have been `$lines`. The point of doing it is that piping the array to `Out-String` formats the inputs.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with $input.

If you do this :

```
Get-Content $file -Wait | Get-Member -InputObject $input
```

Or

```
Get-Content $file -Wait | Get-Member -InputObject $_
```

You will get :

```
Get-Member : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
```

If Get-Member is unable to read the object going through the pipeline, you know that something is very wrong with the object (or the pipelining).

Let's try piping $input to Out-String, like you are doing in your script :

```
Get-Content $file -Wait | Out-String $input
```

You will get :

```
Out-String : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Collections.ArrayList+ArrayListEnumeratorSimple'.
At line:1 char:52
+ get-content '.\netstat anob.txt' -wait | Out-String <<<<  $input
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Out-String], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutStringCommand
```

So, indeed, "Get-Content" -Wait gives you a weird kind of object : a System.Collections.ArrayList+ArrayListEnumeratorSimple .
It looks like it's the result of the GetEnumerator() method from a System.Collections.ArrayList object, or something like that.

Given the fact that Get-Member or even "Get-Member -Force" is unable to read this kind of "Object", from Powershell's point of view, it's not a object.

The workaround would be to drop the -Wait parameter from Get-Content and find another way of achieving what you want, possibly by running Get-Content and then, running "Get-Content -Tail 1" several times in a loop.

Comment: Okay, but some other cmdlets are able to take output from `-Wait` as pipeline input. E.g., I can do `cat $file -Wait | Select-String -Pattern "test"` to filter the output to only lines that match "test". Are we to assume that `Select-String` has special code to handle this particular type?

Answer (score 2):

This is possible if your script accepts pipeline input. You can see it as you have mentioned when you pipe to other cmdlets like `Select-String`. For example defining script.ps1 as:

```
process { Write-Host "line: $input" }
```

Then running

```
1..200 | foreach { add-content -Path test.txt -Value "$_"; start-sleep 1 }
```

in one PowerShell session and

```
gc test.txt -wait | .\script.ps1
```

in another, you can see that each line is piped to the script.

Comment: You can use filters instead of functions with process block too. Filters are aliases for scenarios like this, and process input one at a time, as they arrive.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any way to do what you are asking. -Wait initiates a loop that never ends, the only way to stop is to manually kill it. Since it will always be stuck inside the loop anything you try to do after initiating the loop is never going to process.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
Write-Host $line
```

You should use Write-Output instead. Write-Output sends objects to pipeline, Write-Host directly to host (console).